# How to send attachments using mailgun?

Tags: forms, email-attachments, mailgun

In my form there is section to upload resume I use mailgun API for my mails to send, I am finding trouble for sending attachments using the form.

How to send the attached file along with other details of my form when user submits.

Please see the below image of my form the attachments should be dynamic but not static.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example with Node.js

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
var filename = 'mailgun_logo.png';
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, filename);
var file = fs.readFileSync(filepath);

var attch = new mailgun.Attachment({data: file, filename: filename});

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
  attachment: attch
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Actually there is a field in my form to upload file I need to send that file say for example we both are user we are filling forms(Job application) and we upload our resumes so it is dynamic file not a static one.

Comment: You are literally copying what's in the docs. just point to the docs in a comment